How do I resolve classpath compatibility issues between Spring Boot and Swagger in my application?
I'm having issues with my Spring Boot application when trying to integrate Swagger for API documentation. I receive an error message indicating there are classpath compatibility issues.I don't know how to fix this,whoever helps me I will be eternally grateful.
"Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.plugin.core.support.AbstractTypeAwareSupport$BeansOfTypeTargetSource and org.springframework.util.Assert'
Here is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dio</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-first-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-first-web-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SWAGGER DOCUMENTACAO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


What are the incompatibilities? Provide the exact messages.

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.plugin.core.support.AbstractTypeAwareSupport$BeansOfTypeTargetSource and org.springframework.util.Assert

Please [edit] your question to add the details.

Does this answer your question? why Swagger UI is not working in Spring Boot 3.0 version?

You're using older version of swagger with Spring Boot 3
